# mongoose update millions of records while extracting information

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have a production database with over 5 million customer customer records, each customer document has an embedded array of licenses they have applied for. And example customer document is as follows:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    phoneNumber: 'xxxx',
    // Other customer fields
    licenses: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('...'),
            state: 'PENDING',
            expired: false,
            createdAt: ISODate(''),
            // Other license fields
        },
        // More Licenses for this customer
    ]
}
```

I have been tasked with changing the state of every **PENDING** license applied for during the month of **September** to **REJECTED** and sending an SMS to every customer whose pending permit just got rejected.

Using the `model.where(condition).countDocuments()` I have found that there is over 3 million customers *(not licenses)* matching the aforementioned criteria. Each customer has an average of 9 licenses.

I need assistance coming up with a strategy that won't slow down the system when performing this action. Furthermore, this is around **17GB** of data.

Sending SMS is fine, I can queue details for SMS service. My challenge is processing the licenses while extracting relevant information for SMS.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to create an index on the collection:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "licenses.state": 1 } )
```

Then you shoud do something like that:

```
model.updateMany({}, {
    '$set': {
        'licenses.$[elem].state': 'REJECTED'
    }
}, { arrayFilters: [{
        'elem.createdAt': { $gte: ISODate(....) }
    }],
    multi: true
} ).then(function (doc)){}
```

If you have a replica set and your updates are on the primary instance you should not affect the secondary instances when reading on those once.

If you want to split the update on many batches you can use the _id (already indexed). Of course it depends on your _id format.

Comment: Thank you @Saxon for the response. I came across with this answer looking for info about bulk operations. So, my question is, updateMany uses bulk operations, I mean, it is optimized to be used for millions of updates?

Comment: To perform bulk operations there is Model.bulkWrite() that can perform updateMany, deleteMany, ... with a single bulk write. bulkWrite has the ordered/not ordered mode. The BulkWriteOpResult in the callback or promise gives you the outcome of the whole bulk. How to bulk updates depends on the sharding key, if you have a sharded server. It might be good to let all the shards work at full steam but let a single bulk be processed on a single shard with a size to be tuned. Indeed it's bulkWrite that can use updateMany, non the other way around. Anyway I can't say how mongodb works internally.